# Unable to retrieve data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have some data in my database table and when I am trying to fetch it and display using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and display them on a web page I am failing can some one please help me knowing where I am doing it wrong.

my table(saloon) consists columns:

> saloon_sex
>
> saloon_map
>
> saloon_price
>
> saloon_name
>
> saloon_number
>
> saloon_image
>
> saloon_location
>
> saloon_oh
>
> saloon_oh1
>
> saloon_services
>
> saloon_menu1
>
> saloon_menu2
>
> saloon_menu3
>
> saloon_photo1
>
> saloon_photo2
>
> saloon_photo3
>
> saloon_area

and this is the code

```
<?php 
              $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                            mysqli_select_db($connection,'cmssite') or die (mysqli_error($connection));
            if($connection){
                              echo('connected to database');
                           }
              if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                   if(isset($_POST['area'])) {

                      $search_value = $_POST['area'];
                      $query = mysqli_query( $connection,"select * from saloon where saloon_area LIKE '%$search_value%'");
                if(! $query )
                         {
                               die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($query));
                         }

                   $row=null;
                  // $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                 {      echo  $row['saloon_name'];}     
                 ?>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="images/toni&guysalon.jpg" height="150" width="150"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px;"><?php echo  $row['saloon_name']?></h3>
                    <img src="images/unisex.png" width="15" height="15"> <?php echo $row['saloon_sex']?>
                    <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <img src="images/location.png" width="15" height="15"> Opposite Nerus Emporio, Madhapur
                    <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <img src="images/rupee.png" width="15" height="15"> 400+ For Haircut
                    <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <img src="images/time.png" width="15" height="15"> Mon to Sun - 10:00 AM to 09:30 PM

                </div>
            </div>
                   <?php } }

               ?>
            [p1][1]
```

[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdYjn.jpg)

Comment: where does it fails? the code seems buggy but it should work... (of course you have proper credential for the database connection, right?)

Comment: you ended while with only one echo statement                                                            "while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                 {      echo  $row['saloon_name'];} "                        so your output ends here by echoing all saloon name here

Comment: ok tq for that but i think there is something wrong with my query can u once chechk it if it is correct???

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px;"><?php echo  $row['saloon_name']?></h3>
<img src="images/unisex.png" width="15" height="15"> <?php echo $row['saloon_sex']?>
```

change it

```
<h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px;"><?php echo  $row['saloon_name'];?></h3>
<img src="images/unisex.png" width="15" height="15"> <?php echo $row['saloon_sex'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use conditional `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array`, you will have to have your codes you want to print to be kept inside the braket of the condition. 
You are doing it wrong as you only retrieve, print it and close it.

```
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
             {      echo  $row['saloon_name'];}
```

This is what I will always do when typing it.

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

 <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px;"><?php echo  $row['saloon_name']?></h3>
                <img src="images/unisex.png" width="15" height="15"> <?php echo $row['saloon_sex']?>
                <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                <img src="images/location.png" width="15" height="15"> Opposite Nerus Emporio, Madhapur
                <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                <img src="images/rupee.png" width="15" height="15"> 400+ For Haircut
                <div class="clearfix" style="height:10px;"></div>
                <img src="images/time.png" width="15" height="15"> Mon to Sun - 10:00 AM to 09:30 PM
        </div>
               <?php
               } // closing tag for mysqli_fetch_assoc/array
           ?>
```

You could do it in the way you're doing by retrieving and saving it into meaningful variable:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 $saloonSex = $row['saloon_sex'];
 $saloonPrice = $row['saloon_price'];
 $saloonName = $row['saloon_name'];
 ... etc etc
 <div class="col-md-5">
     <h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px;"><?php echo $saloonName?></h3>
     <img src="images/unisex.png" width="15" height="15"> <?php echo $saloonSex?>
  .....etc etc

  <?php
    } // closing tag for mysqli_fetch_assoc/array
 ?>
```

Hope it solve your problem.